# Relation between chiral symmetry and chiral material

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, symmetry, chirality

There seems to be two types of **chiral**.

One chiral is usually referred to in terms of chiral symmetry or its breaking. It can be in the context of field theories where mass generation mixes left & right fields. It also occurs in symmetry protected topological phases together with time-reversal and particle-hole symmetries, where it can sometimes have the operator $\sigma_z$ in a proper basis.

The other chiral describes material structures when an object cannot be brought to its mirror image with proper rotations, like in enantiomers, magnetochiral effect, helical spin texture and so on.

Are there any connection between them?